# Fetch All Uploaded Images From Facebook in Ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have use Facebook SDK for fetch photos but they provide us picture (for Profile Picture),cover(Cover Photo) but not provide me all photos of user. any one suggest me how to fetch all images from facebook.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/{facebook id}/albums"
                              parameters:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Insert your code here
}];
```

I use above code for get images but its returns no data.
any one have idea about this then please tell me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ask the user for the necessary permissions first? Accessing albums requires `user_photos`.

Comment: yes I already take permission for same

Comment: And `{facebook id}` is the id of the current user, that the access token belongs to? (In such cases you should rather use `/me` in the first place.) Suggest you first of all test this in Graph API Explorer, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer Select your app from the dropdown, get a user access token, and see what result requesting for the request.

Comment: I got Aceess token but whenever I try to fetch data I got                                
 {
    data =     (
    );
}

Comment: Did you test in Graph API Explorer? Debug your access token, or request `/me/permissions` with it, to verify the user actually granted the permission.